# Signal Extraction

Tags: regression, time-series, signal-detection

I have following problem to show:

let scalar valued signal $X_t$ be transmitted at time $t$ and received $Y_t = X_t + \epsilon_t$. Where $\epsilon_t$'s are zero mean noise. Suppose $E[X_t]=0$ for all $t$. And $\operatorname{ Cov} (X_s,X_t)=\alpha\beta^{|s-t|}$, $|\beta|<1$; and $\operatorname{Var} (\epsilon_t)=\gamma$, $\operatorname{Cov} (\epsilon_s,\epsilon_t)=0$ when $s\neq t$; and $\operatorname{Cov} (\epsilon_s,X_t)=0$ any $s$ and $t$. Then the linear least square estimator of $X_t$ for a given $t$ (i.e. the $\hat{X}_t$ minimizes $E[(X_t-\hat{X}_t)^2]$) based upon the $Y_{t-s}$ over the whole time axis ($s$ is integer from $-\infty$ to $\infty$) is:
$$\hat{X}_t = \frac{\alpha\xi}{\beta\gamma(1-\xi^2)}\sum_s\xi^{|s|}Y_{t-s}$$
where $\xi$ is the smaller root of the equation $\alpha+\gamma(1-\beta\xi)(1-\beta/\xi)=0$.

I know that for dependent variable $X$ ($X$ is a scalar) and independent variable $Y=(Y_1,...,Y_m)^T$, the linear least square estimator
$$\hat{X}=a_0 + a^TY$$
can be found as following:
$$a_0 = E[X]-a^TE[Y]$$
and
$$a = V_{YY}^{-1}V_{YX}$$
where
$$V_{YY} = E[(Y-E[Y])(Y-E[Y])^T]$$
$$V_{YX} = E[(Y-E[Y])(X-E[X])]$$

But how to apply this to the above problem, since we have a infinite dimension of independent variables...

Thank you very much for your answer.